# Omnet++ Logging Message/Packet Traffic

Tags: c++, networking, network-programming, simulation, omnet++

I'm running a simulation on Omnet++ 5.7, and I'd like to record the message/packet traffic of the simulation (as indicated in the picture- https://i.stack.imgur.com/SplvU.png).

Despite trying the following methods, I haven't been able to obtain the data in the format I desire.

1.When I enable Eventlog recording, I obtain an elog file, but the data in this file is in a rather complex format.

2.By adding the following commands to the ini file and running it with cmdenv, I get a log file, but the data in this file is still not in the format I want:

```
cmdenv-redirect-output = true
cmdenv-express-mode = false
cmdenv-output-file = logs.txt
```

3.Although there seems to be an option to copy selected data directly from the clipboard, in long simulations, previous records are discarded.

I'm requesting your assistance with this issue.